# ArduinoJSON undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'

Tags: c, json, arduino

I am working on a sketch and I am using ArduinoJSON. I thought I might through this out and see if people have seen this error.

```
WifiNest.cpp.o:(.text._ZN11ArduinoJson9JsonArray7invalidEv[_ZN11ArduinoJson9JsonArray7invalidEv]+0x8): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'
WifiNest.cpp.o:(.text._ZN11ArduinoJson9JsonArray7invalidEv[_ZN11ArduinoJson9JsonArray7invalidEv]+0xc): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'
WifiNest.cpp.o: In function `ArduinoJson::JsonArray::invalid()':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/WifiNest.ino:156: undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/WifiNest.ino:156: undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'
WifiNest.cpp.o: In function `ArduinoJson::JsonObject::invalid()':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/WifiNest.ino:156: undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/WifiNest.ino:156: undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

Here is part of my Arduino code where I create the jsonArray object:

```
char jsonArray [result.length()+1];
result.toCharArray(jsonArray,sizeof(jsonArray));
jsonArray[result.length() + 1] = '\0';

DynamicJsonBuffer json_buf;
JsonObject &root = json_buf.parseObject(jsonArray);
if (!root.success())
{
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
}
```

Here is the JSONArray invalid function:

```
static JsonArray &invalid() {
    static JsonArray instance(NULL);
    return instance;
}
```

Here is the JSONObject invalid function:

```
// Returns a reference an invalid JsonObject.
// This object is meant to replace a NULL pointer.
// This is used when memory allocation or JSON parsing fail.
static JsonObject& invalid() {
    static JsonObject instance(NULL);
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with the following compilation flag:

> `-fno-threadsafe-statics`
>
> Do not emit the extra code to use the routines specified in the C++ ABI for thread-safe initialization of local statics. You can use this option to reduce code size slightly in code that doesn't need to be thread-safe.

See issues [#356](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/356) and [#361](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/361)

Answer (score 1):

For people from future, I got this error when I was compiling C++ code with gcc. Should have been g++ :P

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally used `export CXX=(path)/clang`. Fixed it with `export CXX=(path)/clang++`.

Comment: @AurelBílý really happy that you found it useful :P We all make such mistakes